# Unique values of 2 column NOT in another column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have 3 columns for example team1, team2 and winner

(p.s. I have big dataset I'm just here giving little example)

I want to find who never wins.

So what I thought was to find unique values of team1 and team 2 
and then from unique values, to find which value wont be there in winner list.

```
team1                        team 2                       toss_winner

Kolkata knight riders       delhi daredevil               delhi daredevils

kings XI punjab            pune warriors                 kings XI punjab

delhi daredevil            mumbai indians                delhi daredevil

pune warriors              chennai superkings            chennai superkings

rajasthan royals           gujarat lions                 gujarat lions

Sunrisers Hyderabad         decan chargers               Sunrisers Hyderabad

Royalchallenger Banglore    Kolkata knight riders        Kolkata knight riders

chennai superkings          rajasthan royals             rajasthan royals
```

---

```
a=np.unique(df[['team1', 'team2']])

b=(df["toss_winner"]).unique()
```

Comment: can you add the expected dataframe too? thanks

Comment: Can't you simply add the unique lists of team1 and team2 into a third list? Then take the unique of that, then filter df["toss_winner"] for values not found in that third unique list. Let me know if this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
uniqueTeams = np.unique(np.concatenate([df['team1'].values, df['team2'].values]))

df.loc[~df['toss_winner'].isin(uniqueTeams), 'toss_winner']
```

First, you concatentate the all values of the two columns then look at the unique values. Next you look at the values that arent in our uniqueTeams `~df['toss_winner'].isin(uniqueTeams)`, then look at our 'toss_winner' column.

You have to be careful because if team1 column you have 
'Kolkata knight rider', but in team2 columns you have 'Kolkata knight rider**s**'. These would be treated as unique teams, so you will have to clean your data really before doing anything else.

Comment: i understand what you saying but i just made this data for asking my question here , and after running this code im getting this output   :                                            
 Series([], Name: toss_winner, dtype: object)

Comment: That means that every team in columns team1 and team2 have won!